# Django rest m2m nested serializer create/update nested objects

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model **Scenario**:

```
class Scenario(models.Model):
    stakeholder = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='scenarios', blank=True,)
    tasks = models.ManyToManyField(Task, blank=True)
```

**Task** objects are already created and from my fronted I create a *scenario* by adding a few of the existing *tasks* to it.

Serializer:

```
class ScenarioSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tasks = TaskSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Scenario
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tasks = validated_data.pop('tasks')
        scenario = Scenario.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for task in tasks:
            Task.objects.update(scenario=scenario, **task)
        return scenario
```

Without create() method it throws error:

```
AssertionError: The `.create()` method does not support writable nested fields by default.
Write an explicit `.create()` method for serializer `scenarios.serializers.ScenarioSerializer`, or set `read_only=True` on nested serializer fields.
```

When I added this method, error was gone but it threw:

```
FieldError: Cannot update model field <ManyToManyRel: scenarios.scenario> (only non-relations and foreign keys permitted)
```

What am I doing wrong? I do not want to create new tasks, just create a new scenario and attach existing tasks to it.

**Update**: Task model:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    stakeholder = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='tasks', blank=True, )
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='project_tasks' )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null = True, )
    OFTEN_CHOICES = (
    ('DS', 'Daily several times'),  
    ('DO', 'Daily once'),
    ('WO', 'Weekly once'),
    ('MO', 'Monthly once'),
    ('YO', 'Yearly once'),
    )
    how_often = models.CharField(blank=True, null = True, choices=OFTEN_CHOICES, max_length=2, )
    IMPORTANCE_CHOICES = (
    ('EI', 'Extremely important'),  
    ('RI', 'Rather important'),
    ('LI', 'Less important'),
    )
    how_important_task = models.CharField(blank=True, null = True, choices=IMPORTANCE_CHOICES, max_length=2, )
    role = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null = True, )
    why_perform_task = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null = True, )
    why_important_task = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null = True, )
    sequence_of_actions = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null = True, )
    tools_used = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null = True, )
    special_training_required = models.NullBooleanField(blank=True, null = True, default=False, )
    what_training_required = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null = True, )
    what_can_go_wrong = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null = True, )
    effects_of_task = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null = True, )
    special_vocabulary_used = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null = True, )
    people_involved = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null = True, )
    any_improvements = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null = True, )
    how_important_improvement = models.CharField(blank=True, null = True, choices=IMPORTANCE_CHOICES, max_length=2, )
    benefits_of_improvement = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null = True, )
```

sample request data:

```
{"tasks":[{"id":7,"title":"Seven","how_often":"","how_important_task":"","role":"","why_perform_task":"","why_important_task":null,"sequence_of_actions":"","tools_used":"","special_training_required":null,"what_training_required":"","what_can_go_wrong":"","effects_of_task":"","special_vocabulary_used":"","people_involved":"","any_improvements":"","how_important_improvement":"","benefits_of_improvement":"","stakeholder":2,"project":1}]}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you done first part and now need add method `update` here [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writing-update-methods-for-nested-representations):

for example

```
class ScenarioSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tasks = TaskSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Scenario
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tasks = validated_data.pop('tasks', [])
        instance = Scenario.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for task_data in tasks:
            task = Task.objects.get(pk=task_data.get('id'))
            instance.tasks.add(task)
        return instance 

   def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        tasks = validated_data.pop('tasks', [])
        instance = super().update(instance, validated_data)
        for task_data in tasks:
            task = Task.objects.get(pk=task_data.get('id'))
            instance.tasks.add(task)
        return instance
```

Comment: After replacing create() with update it is still throwing: `AssertionError: The `.create()` method does not support writable nested fields by default.
Write an explicit `.create()` method for serializer `scenarios.serializers.ScenarioSerializer`, or set `read_only=True` on nested serializer fields.` error

Comment: no you should add `update` not replace `create`. restore the create method please

Comment: Okay, but is my create method correct? I have a feeling that it is partially incorrect. It again threw me: `FieldError: Cannot update model field <ManyToManyRel: scenarios.scenario> (only non-relations and foreign keys permitted).`

Comment: add you model `Task` and example of date to the question

Comment: Kindly check now

Comment: try new version please

Comment: It is throwing `DoesNotExist: Task matching query does not exist.`

Comment: glad to help you!)

Comment: Spelling mistake in reply. Dear Respondent, please change      "instance =super().update(instance, alidated_data)"
 to    " instance = super().update(instance, validated_data)"

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do the same but my update method is never called because I have a unique constraint on my nested serialized object, so DRF returns error 400 due to `is_valid` throwing an exception before even getting to my `update` method. Any tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved by following the steps in this post https://lynxbee.com/solved-the-create-method-does-not-support-writable-nested-fields-by-default/.

```
pip install drf_writable_nested
```

```py
from drf_writable_nested import WritableNestedModelSerializer

class YourSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer, serializers.ModelSerializer):
   pass
```

Comment: Don't hesitate to provide more details on how you solved it and how it could be applied to this problem.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged here. Please provide some context to your answer and consider adding a summary of why your answer may be preferable to the other answers provided.

Comment: @ZheniaKviatkivskyi `WritableNestedModelSerializer` already inherits `serializers.ModelSerializer`. This class defintion you mentioned should not be used.